# Html.Dropdownlist selected value not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, selected

In my project, Html.DropdownList could not display its selected value.It displays the initial value of the list.My controller and view codes are given below:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        PERMISSION permission = permissionManager.Find(id);
        ViewBag.MODULE_ID = new SelectList(moduleManager.GetAll(), "ID", "TITLE",permission.MODULE_ID);
        return View(permission);
    }
```

View :

```
@Html.DropDownList("MODULE_ID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.MODULE_ID, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

But if I write :

```
@Html.DropDownList("MODULE_ID", String.Empty)
```

It works fine.but I have to add the class="form-control".What should be solution?
**UPDATE:**
I have changed the ViewBag name from ViewBag.MODULE_ID to *ViewBag.ModuleList*. It may conflicts with the name of the dropdownlist. and now It works fine.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are no values displayed, or is it just that it doesn't initially select the element you expected? What does your debugger tell you?

Comment: It displays the initial value of the list. not the selected one.

Comment: What are the types of `ID` and `TITLE`. `int` and `string`?

Comment: Use the debugger to inspect the newly created SelectList. Check whether the correct SelectListItem has its Selected property set to true.

Comment: then that *should* work. Are you sure this simply is not a case of using `Ctrl-F5`?

Comment: I am sure .@arserbin3

Comment: Are you sure that `permission.ID` is one of the available values in that `<select>` field's `<option>`s? Perhaps it needs to be `permission.Module_ID`? It may be helpful to include your `PERMISSION` class definition, as well as what `GetAll()` returns.

Comment: @arserbin3 thanks a lot.Its Permission.MODULE_ID. I edited the code. but its not working.

Comment: At this point then, would need to see the `PERMISSION` class properties definition and what return type `GetAll()` is. I'm assuming it's some kind of `IEnumerable<MODULE>`, so would also be helpful to know that `MODULE.ID` property is an `int` or what.

Comment: GetAll Method :  public List<MODULE> GetAll() 
        {
            return db.MODULEs.ToList();
        }

Comment: I have edited my question. please check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have changed the ViewBag name from ViewBag.MODULE_ID to ViewBag.ModuleList. It may conflicts with the name of the dropdownlist. and now It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the `form-control` class in the wrong parameter. currently it is being added as the option label.

Use this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("MODULE_ID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.MODULE_ID, "-- Select --",  new { @class = "form-control" })
```

---

On a side note, you should consider using a ViewModel class and doing away with both the magic string `"MODULE_ID"` and the `ViewBag` magic property. A ViewModel class allows you to strongly name things without casting, like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MODULE_ID, Model.Modules, "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

It's a subtle looking change but everything is compile time checked.

Comment: If I add the option label. It displays the label "--Select--" not the selected value.

Comment: That's only because no value is being set as selected then. If your `new SelectList(..., 47)` is working properly, when you view the page source in your browser it should have an `<option value="47" selected="selected">My Module</option>`. If it doesn't, the first option is selected.

Comment: I debug the program again.I have found the selectList with selected value 51 which is a valid value.But in the view page it could not display the selected value. But if I wrote :@Html.DropDownList("MODULE_ID", String.Empty) .It displays the selected value. :(

Comment: was there an `<option value="51">51's Title</option>` in the HTML when you used `moduleManager.GetAll()` and `ViewBag.MODULE_ID`?

Comment: I found :<option value="51">User Group</option> in my html. :|

Comment: May be IEnumerable<SelectListItem> could not get the selected value.

Comment: the `bool Selected` property is in the `SelectListItem` class, not in the `SelectList` class. So `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` will contain it fine. And it is verified to work fine for me.

Comment: I have changed the ViewBag name from ViewBag.MODULE_ID to _ViewBag.ModuleList_. It may conflicts with the name of the dropdownlist. and now It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

what works for me according to previous solution:
in controller:

```
ViewBag.VCenter = new SelectList(db.VirtualMachinesData.Where(x => x.IsVCenter == true).ToList(), "Id", "IPAddress","80"); ;
```

in View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("v", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.VCenter, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Important note: the name of dropdownlist -"v"- must be different from the name of viewbag -"VCenter"-, if same names it didn't work.